Adapting this formula to Python Polars, stuck on Euluers Number and Exponent
I have the following formula

Citation: https://www.chess-journal.com/evaluatingSharpness1.html
In terms of my data frame:
w = "win"
d = "draw"
l = "loss"

and e is our buddy Euler's number.
What would be a tidy way of representing that final component? And should I use math.e for the e?
This is what I have so far
df = df.with_columns(
    ((pl.min_horizontal(pl.col("win"), pl.col("loss")) / 50) * (333 / pl.col("draw"))).alias("sharpness")
)


I believe you're looking for exp()

As in your case you need to exponent of the constant e, you can use pure polars expression - Expr.exp():
def sharpness(w, l, d):
    a = pl.min_horizontal(w, l) / 50
    b = 333 / d
    c = -(w + l) / 1000
    return a * b / (1 + c.exp())

df.with_columns(
    sharpness(pl.col("win"), pl.col("loss"), pl.col("draw")).alias("sharpness")
)

Just a note, there's a way to apply exponent to the column - Expr.pow()

Your c = -(w + d) / 1000 should be c = -(w + l) / 1000

One little thing that makes using these helpers a little nicer is to do if isinstance(w, str): w=pl.col(w) that way they can optionally take str and it'll treat it as a column. You have to do it with all the inputs or you could hack a loop with locals()
